# f linear with $\|f(x)\| = \|x\|$ then $\langle f(x),f(y)\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle$

Tags: inner-products

On a vector Space $V$ with scalarproduct $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and $f : V \to V$ linear with $\|f(x)\| = \|x\|$ for all $x$ in $V$ then prove that $\langle f(x),f(y)\rangle= \langle x,y\rangle $ for all $x,y$ in $V$

I tried this :
$\langle x,y\rangle\leq \|x\|\cdot\|y\| = \|f(x)\|\cdot\|f(y)\|$ 
and same $\langle f(x),f(y)\rangle \leq \|f(x)\|\cdot\|f(y)\| = \|x\|\cdot\|y\|$ 
I don't know how to get the eqaulity though. Any help? Thank you

Comment: If $A\leq B$ and $B\leq A$ then $A=B.$

Comment: I don't see it here though. both left sides are small or equal to the same right side but this does not make them equal.

Comment: This is a duplicate!

Answer (score 4):

Here we can use the polarization identity of the Euclidean norm (i.e. $\|x-y\|_2^2 = \|x\|_2^2 + \|y\|_2^2 - 2\langle x, y \rangle$)

Since $f$ is linear we note that

$$\|x-y\| = \|f(x-y)\| = \|f(x) - f(y)\|.$$

The square both sides and apply polarization to both sides to get

$$\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 - 2\langle x, y \rangle = \|f(x)\|^2 + \|f(y)\|^2 - 2\langle f(x), f(y) \rangle. $$

Use the fact that $f$ preserves the norms, we can simplify and get

$$\langle x, y \rangle = \langle f(x), f(y) \rangle. $$

---

Edit: This proof is only true when working over $\mathbb{R}$ as pointed out in the comment. (Can be modified for $\mathbb{C}$ by looking $x-iy$ as well.)

Comment: Technically, this only works when the field is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are obviously duplicates. You see links to the same question on the right hand pane of this page.